# CEF crashes on closing NSWindow in Macbook PRO(Only on Touchpad not for mouse click)

Tags: objective-c, macos, crash, nswindow, chromium-embedded

I have integrated CEF Framework into my project.

Its working fine for mouse based window close but it crashes If I use inbuilt touch pad of mac book pro while closing browser pop up window.

The pop up window is generate by CEF.

I am able to reproduce the crash like above most of the times.

Here is the crash log

> Process:               cefclient [1271] Path:
>   /Users/USER/Documents/*/cefclient.app/Contents/MacOS/cefclient
>   Identifier:            com.genband.omni.mac Version:
>   1.0.0.30 (1.0.0.30) Code Type:             X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:        ??? [1] Responsible:           cefclient [1271] User
>   ID:               501
>
> Date/Time:             2016-07-07 14:54:14.865 +0530 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.10.2 (14C1514) Report Version:        11 Anonymous UUID:
>   0F54FCED-4D82-FEB9-5CD2-3A541BF3C022
>
> Sleep/Wake UUID:       C774E441-04B7-4295-A913-3AD622E6B6F3
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 4300 seconds Time Since Wake:       710 seconds
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  CrBrowserMain  Dispatch queue:
>   com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000443e46cfbec0
>
> VM Regions Near 0x443e46cfbec0:
>       mapped file            0000000124936000-0000000124b36000 [ 2048K] rw-/rwx SM=ALI  /private/var/folders/*/*.3KjSNY
>   --> 
>       MALLOC_NANO            0000600000000000-0000600000200000 [ 2048K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV
>
> Application Specific Information: objc_msgSend() selector name:
>   respondsToSelector: Performing @selector(_close:) from sender
>   _NSThemeCloseWidget 0x608000186320
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: CrBrowserMain  Dispatch queue:
>   com.apple.main-thread 0   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x00007fff9303f0dd objc_msgSend + 29 1   com.apple.AppKit
>   0x00007fff87802735 -[NSWindow **close] + 312 2   libsystem_trace.dylib
>   0x00007fff84178cd7 _os_activity_initiate + 75 3   com.apple.AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff877b9b71 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 452 4
>
>   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff877b9970 -[NSControl
>   sendAction:to:] + 86 5   com.apple.AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff8798f86c __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke + 131 6
>   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff84178cd7
>   _os_activity_initiate + 75 7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff87802509 -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 144 8
>
>   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff84178cd7
>   _os_activity_initiate + 75 9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff87801d66 -[NSButtonCell performClick:] + 1027 10 
>   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff83eaecdc
>   __NSThreadPerformPerform + 293 11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90285681
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17 12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff902778dc
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 476 13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90276e3f __CFRunLoopRun + 927 14  com.apple.CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff90276858 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296 15  com.apple.HIToolbox 
>   0x00007fff8ab26aef RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235 16 
>   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8ab2686a
>   ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431 17  com.apple.HIToolbox
>   0x00007fff8ab266ab _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter +
>   71 18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff875eaf81
>   _DPSNextEvent + 964 19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff875ea730 -[NSApplication
>   nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 194 20 
>   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff875de593 -[NSApplication
>   run] + 594 21  org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x000000010d1b7c81
>   0x10d080000 + 1277057 22  org.chromium.ContentShell.framework
>   0x000000010d1b72e4 0x10d080000 + 1274596 23 
>   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x000000010d1ef893 0x10d080000 +
>   1505427 24  org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x000000010d1dd80d
>   0x10d080000 + 1431565 25  com.genband.omni.mac
>   0x000000010ceb9d69 client::MainMessageLoopStd::Run() + 9
>   (main_message_loop_std.cc:15) 26  com.genband.omni.mac
>   0x000000010cee6c12 main + 2354 (cefclient_mac.mm:1747) 27 
>   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8433d5c9 start + 1

Any suggestions are highly welcome

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `window_` delegate to `nil`, in `dealloc` method of `root_window_mac.mm` cleared the crash problem for me.